# Subtext 2.1.2 SecurityException

Tags: .net-3.5, iis-7, securityexception, subtext

I'm trying to get Subtext 2.1.2 working on my local machine (IIS7).
I downloaded the zip file (http://subtext.googlecode.com/files/SubText-2.1.2.zip) and extracted it, then created the application in the directory.
Now, when I try to run the application it throws a security exception (note: I am running full trust).

Here's the exception details:

```
Security Exception
Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file.

Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Web.AspNetHostingPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Web.AspNetHostingPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.]
   System.Reflection.Assembly._GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase) +0
   System.Reflection.Assembly.GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError) +36
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildResultCompiledType.GetPreservedAttributes(PreservationFileReader pfr) +54
   System.Web.Compilation.PreservationFileReader.ReadFileInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, String preservationFile, Int64 hashCode) +496
   System.Web.Compilation.PreservationFileReader.ReadBuildResultFromFile(VirtualPath virtualPath, String preservationFile, Int64 hashCode) +91
   System.Web.Compilation.DiskBuildResultCache.GetBuildResult(String cacheKey, VirtualPath virtualPath, Int64 hashCode) +66
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetBuildResultFromCacheInternal(String cacheKey, Boolean keyFromVPP, VirtualPath virtualPath, Int64 hashCode) +176
   System.Web.Compilation.ApplicationBuildProvider.GetGlobalAsaxBuildResult(Boolean isPrecompiledApp) +65
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileGlobalAsax() +51
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled() +337

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.4927; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.4927
```

Any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from Windows Vista, Windows stores the zone information for any files you download from the Internet.
You have to explicitly *unblock* these files before they can be executed.
The easiest way to unblock the individual files is to *unblock the zip file* ***before*** *extracting it*.
Right-click the zip file and choose "Properties", then click the "Unblock" button.

There are some other steps you need to perform in order to get Subtext up and running, but I suggest you look at using the [Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/) to perform the installation.
The Web Platform Installer will not only ensure that the application is configured correctly, but will also ensure that any pre-requisites are installed too.